# ubuntu 22.04 python3-dev:amd64

Tags: 22.04, 64-bit, python3, development

After upgrade 20.04 to 22.04 Python3 failed installation. When I run the apt-get upgrade or install python3  it begins but always hits this error:

```
Setting up python3 (3.10.4-0ubuntu2) ...
running python rtupdate hooks for python3.10...
/usr/share/games/pathological/pathological.py:137: SyntaxWarning: "is" with a literal. Did you mean "=="?
  if colorkey is -1:
  File "/usr/share/games/renpy/launcher/game/gui7/code.py", line 283
    l = re.sub(ur'_\((\".*?\")\)', replace, l)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
error running python rtupdate hook renpy
dpkg: error processing package python3 (--configure):
 installed python3 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 4
```

I have tried manual Pyton3 install, tried install Python3-dev, I tried removing Python 3 (which also whacked a lot of specific other apps) and then install, tried all from https://linux-packages.com/ubuntu-jammy-jellyfish/package/python3-full
tried all from https://phoenixnap.com/kb/ubuntu-fix-broken-packages, and several other things, like sudo apt-get clean-all, sudo apt-get purge, ...satisfy, etcetera.

?? ouch !!

here is the sudo apt-get upgrade message set:

```
$ sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  cdrdao cdrskin dvd+rw-tools growisofs k3b-data k3b-i18n libburn4 libcddb2
  libdca0 libdirectfb-1.7-7 libdvbpsi10 libdvbv5-0 libebml5 libenca0
  libfreeaptx0 libgraphicsmagick-q16-3 libgupnp-igd-1.0-4 libiso9660-11
  libkate1 libldacbt-enc2 libltc11 libmatroska7 libmjpegutils-2.1-0 libmpcdec6
  libmpeg2encpp-2.1-0 libmplex2-2.1-0 libmujs1 libnice10 libopenh264-6
  libopenmpt-modplug1 libopenni2-0 libplacebo192 libqt5sensors5 libqt5webkit5
  libresid-builder0c2a libsidplay1v5 libsidplay2 libsixel1 libspatialaudio0
  libsrtp2-1 libturbojpeg libva-glx2 libvcdinfo0 libvo-aacenc0 libvorbisidec1
  libwildmidi2 libxine2-console libxine2-doc libxine2-gnome libxine2-x
  libzbar0 mplayer-skins rtmpdump vcdimager vlc-bin vlc-data vlc-l10n
  vlc-plugin-notify vlc-plugin-qt vlc-plugin-samba vlc-plugin-skins2
  vlc-plugin-video-output vlc-plugin-video-splitter vlc-plugin-visualization
  youtube-dl
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
2133 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Setting up python3 (3.10.4-0ubuntu2) ...
running python rtupdate hooks for python3.10...
/usr/share/games/pathological/pathological.py:137: SyntaxWarning: "is" with a literal. Did you mean "=="?
  if colorkey is -1:
  File "/usr/share/games/renpy/launcher/game/gui7/code.py", line 283
    l = re.sub(ur'_\((\".*?\")\)', replace, l)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
error running python rtupdate hook renpy
dpkg: error processing package python3 (--configure):
 installed python3 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 4
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-enet:
 python3-enet depends on python3 (<< 3.11); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.
 python3-enet depends on python3 (>= 3.10~); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-enet (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                          dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of sssd-common:
 sssd-common depends on python3; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package sssd-common (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                          No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
        dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of sssd-proxy:
 sssd-proxy depends on sssd-common (= 2.6.3-1ubuntu3.1); however:
  Package sssd-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package sssd-proxy (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of cupp:
 cupp depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package cupp (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gconf2:
 gconf2 depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package gconf2 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-zipp:
 python3-zipp depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-zipp (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-click:
 python3-click depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-click (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-xdg:
 python3-xdg depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-xdg (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-chm:
 python3-chm depends on python3 (<< 3.11); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.
 python3-chm depends on python3 (>= 3.10~); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.
 python3-chm depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-chm (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of androguard:
 androguard depends on python3-click; however:
  Package python3-click is not configured yet.
 androguard depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package androguard (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-rpm:
 python3-rpm depends on python3 (<< 3.11); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.
 python3-rpm depends on python3 (>= 3.10~); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.
 python3-rpm depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-rpm (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-distupgrade:
 python3-distupgrade depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-distupgrade (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-tld:
 python3-tld depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-tld (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-networkx:
 python3-networkx depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-networkx (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-markupsafe:
 python3-markupsafe depends on python3 (<< 3.11); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.
 python3-markupsafe depends on python3 (>= 3.10~); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.
 python3-markupsafe depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-markupsafe (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-sss:
 python3-sss depends on python3 (<< 3.11); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.
 python3-sss depends on python3 (>= 3.10~); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.
 python3-sss depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-sss (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-nose:
 python3-nose depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-nose (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of game-data-packager:
 game-data-packager depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package game-data-packager (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of printer-driver-postscript-hp:
 printer-driver-postscript-hp depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package printer-driver-postscript-hp (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-webencodings:
 python3-webencodings depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-webencodings (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-ldap3:
 python3-ldap3 depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-ldap3 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-defcon:
 python3-defcon depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-defcon (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-fontpens:
 python3-fontpens depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-fontpens (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-editorconfig:
 python3-editorconfig depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-editorconfig (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of openprinting-ppds:
 openprinting-ppds depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package openprinting-ppds (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of software-properties-common:
 software-properties-common depends on python3; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.
 software-properties-common depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package software-properties-common (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-psutil:
 python3-psutil depends on python3 (<< 3.11); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.
 python3-psutil depends on python3 (>= 3.10~); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.
 python3-psutil depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-psutil (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of apport:
 apport depends on python3; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package apport (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-tz:
 python3-tz depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-tz (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-bs4:
 python3-bs4 depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-bs4 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-sqlalchemy:
 python3-sqlalchemy depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-sqlalchemy (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                            dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-natsort:
 python3-natsort depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-natsort (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of aircrack-ng:
 aircrack-ng depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package aircrack-ng (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-fonttools:
 python3-fonttools depends on python3 (<< 3.11); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.
 python3-fonttools depends on python3 (>= 3.10~); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.
 python3-fonttools depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-fonttools (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                            dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of unoconv:
 unoconv depends on python3; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package unoconv (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-apport:
 python3-apport depends on python3:any (>= 3.0~); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-apport (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of netplan.io:
 netplan.io depends on python3; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package netplan.io (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-ifaddr:
 python3-ifaddr depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-ifaddr (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-cupshelpers:
 python3-cupshelpers depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-cupshelpers (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                            dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-matplotlib-inline:
 python3-matplotlib-inline depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-matplotlib-inline (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-monotonic:
 python3-monotonic depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-monotonic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-fs:
 python3-fs depends on python3-tz; however:
  Package python3-tz is not configured yet.
 python3-fs depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-fs (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-sgmllib3k:
 python3-sgmllib3k depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-sgmllib3k (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-routes:
 python3-routes depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-routes (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of ssh-audit:
 ssh-audit depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package ssh-audit (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-mysqldb:
 python3-mysqldb depends on python3 (<< 3.11); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.
 python3-mysqldb depends on python3 (>= 3.10~); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.
 python3-mysqldb depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-mysqldb (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                            dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-six:
 python3-six depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-six (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-bson:
 python3-bson depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-bson (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                            dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-simplejson:
 python3-simplejson depends on python3 (<< 3.11); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.
 python3-simplejson depends on python3 (>= 3.10~); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.
 python3-simplejson depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-simplejson (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: too many errors, stopping
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python3
 python3-enet
 sssd-common
 sssd-proxy
 cupp
 gconf2
 python3-zipp
 python3-click
 python3-xdg
 python3-chm
 androguard
 python3-rpm
 python3-distupgrade
 python3-tld
 python3-networkx
 python3-markupsafe
 python3-sss
 python3-nose
 game-data-packager
 printer-driver-postscript-hp
 python3-webencodings
 python3-ldap3
 python3-defcon
 python3-fontpens
 python3-editorconfig
 openprinting-ppds
 software-properties-common
 python3-psutil
 apport
 python3-tz
 python3-bs4
 python3-sqlalchemy
 python3-natsort
 aircrack-ng
 python3-fonttools
 unoconv
 python3-apport
 netplan.io
 python3-ifaddr
 python3-cupshelpers
 python3-matplotlib-inline
 python3-monotonic
 python3-fs
 python3-sgmllib3k
 python3-routes
 ssh-audit
 python3-mysqldb
 python3-six
 python3-bson
 python3-simplejson
Processing was halted because there were too many errors.
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Your issue is with `/usr/share/games/pathological/pathological.py` - did you install any Python games recently before upgrading?  The upgrade between Ubuntu 20.04 and Ubuntu 22.04 (Python 3.8 -> Python 3.10) introduces a LOT of strictness into the Python libraries that break older applications.  You may need to uninstall your game *first* then do your update

Comment: Thank you. This "renpy" was apparently a very old game that had been installed at some past time and some of it was remaining. I used Synaptic to find and delete it completely, at which point the many installations that had failed went ahead and ran and all seems good now.

Answer (score 1):

I was really surprised to learn that some old game I installed for my kids could completely derail my OS upgrade. It was easily fixed, though:

```
sudo apt remove renpy
sudo apt dist-upgrade
```